# Nativescript 5.3.1 TypeError: Cannot read property 'getViewById' of undefined

Tags: nativescript

after upgrading from {N}5.2 to 5.3.1 am getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getViewById' of undefined` but it worked previously before the upgrade

Comment: This seems to specific to your code, can you share a Playground sample where your issue can be reproduced?

Comment: it works in playground but not device , even the actionbar isn't there! i've been getting view id like ```var lb=page.getViewById('label')``` but after ``tns update`` project updated alright

Comment: What you mean by not on device. You run the preview app on device, you mean it doesn't work on local project? Then it must something specific to your project.

Comment: yes it is specific to my project but only after an update, before update everything worked

Comment: @Manoj how do i use the page object inside a function other than onNavigatinTo or pageLoaded? thats the root cause, before i exported the page object in a viewmodel     ``` exports.submit=function (args) {
  var page=model.page;    
  var lid=args.getViewById("li");  .........}```

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=8tmxry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! i just needed a frame `<Frame id="status-root" defaultPage="account"/>` before loading the page, its new in {N} 5.3 so its either the frame alone or

```
<Frame id="mypage" >
  <page>
  //page content
  </page>
</Frame>
```